# django image field - magic

Tags: python, django

i define upload_to = 'products', my media_root is /var/www/work.sanremo-dv.ru/media/

In debugger image.path equal /var/www/work.sanremo-dv.ru/media/imagename.ext - without upload_to dir. Phisical image stored by /var/www/work.sanremo-dv.ru/media/products/imagename.ext why?

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should set `upload_to` with end slash?

```
upload_to = 'products/'
```